# How to use Sliding Menu with ActionBar Sherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-sliding

I am trying to use a sliding menu in my existing project where action bar Sherlock is used. But I am unable to do that. If you can give me a simple demo or tutorial to show me how to do so, that would be great? Do we have to use the fragments for the sliding menu?

**Update:**

How do I change the Activity when the user clicks on an item of the Sliding Menu list?

Is there a demo? please help.

Comment: @CommonsWare look at this : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do as it says in https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

1. Create your sliding layout.
2. In onCreate:

   ```
   setBehindContentView(R.layout.slide_menu);
   getSlidingMenu().setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
   getSlidingMenu().setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
   getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.actionbar_home_width);
   getSlidingMenu().setBehindScrollScale(0.25f);
   ```
3. And in the activity:

   ```
   @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case android.R.id.home:
           toggle();
           return true;
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```

Comment: can you put here slide_menu.xml

Answer (score 10):

Edit library `SliderMenu` to extents `SherlockActivity`

```
public class SlidingActivity extends SherlockActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {
```

Comment: Your answer was a bit vague but it led me to the solution.

Comment: when I implement SlidingActivityBase I get these empty methods and when I call them they return null. What to fill their bodies with?

Comment: @Smitty would you explain to me?

Comment: @Kenji i was confused where SlidingActivity actually was and since I'm new to Java/Android/Sherlock, I did not know exactly where to go. I did not think I would need to go into the actual library itself and extend it. Anyhow, your answer did lead me to the solution so thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

I did not find it very clear from the instructions on the ([SlidingMenu GitGub](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu))

Heres a screenshot to make it more clear:
[image]