# How to implement SlideMenu and ActionbarSherlock Correctly

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Good day, I am trying to implement jfeinstein slide menu with a ListView layout and ActionBarSherlock in my app and for some reason, i can't seem to get the implementation correctly on the SlideMenu. From my understanding, when using the SlideMenu library with ActionBarSherlock, you have to extend to SherlockActivity in the SlideMenu Activity you plan to use.

here is my implementation: i will post only the relevant code here.

```
 public class MyActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
ListView slidinglist;
private SlidingAdapter SlidingAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_dashboard);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_layout);

          getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            //Enable home button
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            //Home as up display
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            /*get array from the slidemenu items in value folder */
            String[] text_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sliding_menus);
            TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.sliding_menu_images);

            final Context context=this;
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null, true);

            slidinglist = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.slidemenu_listView);
            SlidingAdapter = new SlidingAdapter(this, R.layout.slide_menu_item, text_items, imgs);
            slidinglist.setAdapter(SlidingAdapter);

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setFadeEnabled(true);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.setBehindOffset(100);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        //menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_layout);
        menu.setMenu(v);


    }
```

menu_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/slidemenu_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter class:

```
public class SlidingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
         Context mContext;
         private int ViewResourceId; 
         private String[] mstring;
         TypedArray icons;

        public SlidingAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, String[] items, TypedArray images ){
            super(context, resourceId, items);

            mContext = context;
            ViewResourceId = resourceId;
            mstring = items;
            icons = images;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            Log.d(TAG, "lenght of string is" + mstring.length);
            return mstring.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position){
            return mstring[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position){
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(ViewResourceId, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();


              holder.imageview = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.slidemenu_image_item);
              holder.text_title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.slidemenu_textview_id);
              holder.arrowImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.slidemenu_arrow_id);

              convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
            else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            //set Array text values defined in xml to textview
            String title = mstring[position];
            holder.text_title.setText(title);

            //set Array icons values defined in xml to textview
            holder.imageview.setImageDrawable(icons.getDrawable(position));

            return convertView;
        }


    }

     class ViewHolder {
        TextView text_title;
        ImageView imageview;
        ImageView arrowImageView;
    }
```

i am getting a blank screen in the slide Menu. What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the SlidingAdapter populating correctly?

Comment: @AdriánRodríguez i guess so. i will add that code as well.

Comment: @AdriánRodríguez i have added the adapter code.. but can't see anything wrong with it

Comment: Yes, the adapter may not be the problem. Since I don't see the error if there's any, I'll post the code that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It's working for me.

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    private ActionBar ab;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.side_menu);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final int width = display.getWidth();

        ListView mMenuLateral = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_lateral);
        mMenuLateral.setAdapter(new MenuLateralAdapter(getApplicationContext(), vibraCallback));
        mMenuLateral.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.divider));
        mMenuLateral.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
        mMenuLateral.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             ...
        }

        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME); 
        ab.setCustomView(actionBarCustomView);
        ab.setIcon(R.drawable.action_bar_icon_main);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        menu = getSlidingMenu();
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
        menu.setShadowWidth(35);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindWidth(width * 3 / 4);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: thanks for the code. Please could you tell me what your side_menu and activity_main_fragment layout consist, just in case.

Comment: thanks so much! it works now. only 2 thing i changed was menu = getSlidingMenu() instead of what i had earlier and removed the menu.attachToActivity(..) which i will have to read a bit more why. Thanks once again.

Comment: what is different between setContentView and setBehindContentView?

Comment: setContentView sets up the above view, while setBehindContentView sets up the below view. Imagine the facebook application, the above view would be your timeline, and the below view would be the menu that appears when you click on the upper-left button.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need extends yours Activity to Sherlock then Implement SlidingMenu

Try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14126158/1909953